# Animating marginLeft with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't figure out to animate marginLeft with jQuery. I need it to subtract 938px every time a user clicks on a link, which was working fine when I was using `.css()`, but I can't figure out how to make it work with `.animate()`.

```
$("#full-wrapper #full").animate({
    marginLeft, -=938px
}, 500);
```

Can anyone figure out why this doesn't work? This was my CSS version:

```
$("#full-wrapper #full").css("marginLeft","-=938px");
```

I was using CSS3 for animation, but need to make it work in older browsers.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your code, as you are passing parameters in an object to `animate()` you should use `:` not `,` to delimit each attribute. Try this:

```
$("#full-wrapper #full").animate({
    marginLeft: '-=938px'
}, 500);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rHd6C/)

Answer (score 3):

Replace comman(,) by colon(:).

```
$("#full-wrapper #full").animate({
    marginLeft: "-=938px"
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#full-wrapper #full").animate({
    marginLeft: '-=938px'
}, 500);
```