# jQuery margin-left not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to animate a div to basically slide left and move out of view, but it's simply not working and i can't figure out why. I've added the code below and, of course, i've included the jQuery script.

HTML

```
<div class="site-main" id="main">

<div class="main-content" id="main-content">
    <div class="closeContent"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
    <div class="content-area" id="primary">

        <article class="post-22 page type-page status-publish hentry" id="post-22">

           <div class="innerRightCol">
               <h2>Text</h2>
           </div>

        </article><!-- #post-## -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
</div><!-- #main-content -->

</div>
```

CSS

```
.site-main {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    margin-left: 255px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 560px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".closeContent").click(function (){
        $(".main-content").animate({"margin-left": '-=255px'});
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating marginLeft with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229921/animating-marginleft-with-jquery)

Comment: On line 36 in your HTML you have a `;` which should be there.. you will see that error in your console. Remove it and it might work.

Comment: this code actually works for me...  I just had to put some text in the `<i class="fa fa-times"></i>` to have something to click on.

Comment: Adding text didn't help (to test).

Comment: Could you post CSS for `.main-content`?

Comment: Hey, you can see from the link above :)

Answer (score 0):

.closeContent is blank , you cant click unless you add some text or providing width and height for the div.

Comment: It is actually clickable, since when i do `.hide()` instead of the animate, it hides it.

Comment: where are you doing .hide().

Comment: I'm simply changing `.animate({"margin-left": '-=255px'});` with `.hide()`

Comment: you cant do click on the element which is visible, i would suggest you can set the opacity to 0.

Comment: can you the post the code for hiding, that ll help to debug.

Comment: I don't want to hide it, i still want to animate the margin left to "hide it", i was just demonstrating that clicking the button activates the code above. I have set the code to `$(".site-main").css("margin-left", "-305px");` and that works, but why won't the animation work? Really weird!

Comment: i couldnt exactly figure whats the issue , but what i believe is , that element would have moved to the margin-left but it wont be visible to the user , it can be either because of style overflow or z-index of other elements, so this element might be hidden under some other element. try inspecting the element with the id.

Comment: I went through the site and found that 'main-content' is there in the page even after clicking the close button  but its hiding under the #mainNav ..