# How to load html pages with slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three pages on my website. `index.html`, `services.html` and `company.html`. What I need is when a user clicks on services link, then the page will load from the left or right side instead of the load as normal. I don't know perfectly but it may be possible with some Jquery elements like `data-transition="left"`, `data-transition="base"`, `data-name="services"`. Is there any plugin to load pages from left or right. I need this, Please help me.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "load" the page from left to right, but what you can do is:

1. On your services page
2. create a "wrapper div" around your page content, and
3. off-set the content inside the wrapper div to beyond the far right of the page, then
4. use jQuery/javascript on page load (i.e. inside the `$(document).ready()` function to animate the content back to normal position.

So, something like this (untested):

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="inner-wrap">
            //page content goes here
            //Actually, I might create an inner div here and off-set/animate that one...
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

CSS:
#inner-wrap{position:relative;margin-left:100vw;}

jQuery:
$(document).ready(function(
    //use jQuery .animate() method to slide the marginLeft param back to 0.
){});
```

Note that jQuery's animate method does not use `margin-left` - rather, it uses `marginLeft`. Like that.

Example:

[Animating marginLeft with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229921/animating-marginleft-with-jquery)

### Update:

You can use the same idea that was suggested above, but you only need a single file (e.g. `index.html`) for the entire website, and the "pages" are all just DIVs, and you can use jQuery/javascript to "change pages".

For example:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="page1" class="pagex">
            //page ONE content goes here
        </div><!-- .pagex -->
        <div id="page2" class="pagex">
            //page TWO content goes here
        </div><!-- .pagex -->
        <div id="page3" class="pagex">
            //page THREE content goes here
        </div><!-- .pagex -->
    </div>
</body>

CSS:
#wrapper{position:relative;}
.pagex{position:absolute;top:0;left:100vw;}
```

Concepts you need to understand:

a) `z-index` -- allows you to position one div on top of another

b) `position:absolute` -- removes the div from the HTML flow and allows you to position it anywhere on the screen, even over-top of other divs

Comment: See update to my answer. As for making this approach work with bootstrap, you can experiment with that on a MINIMAL TEST SITE. But the approach in my UPDATE (added to the answer) will work.

Comment: NOTE that you need to do a lot of experimenting with very simple examples of the above. DO NOT simply attempt to implement the full solution on your full project - you will spend many, many, many unnecessary hours. GO SIMPLE, figure it out first, then implement.

Comment: Please check this link. http://barbajs.org/demos.html. it is same what i want but when i am trying from localhost, it is not working

Comment: Sorry, I'd love to help further but cannot spend the time. Use the information I gave you above to solve this. Have you seen [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp)? Perhaps you have, but if not it is VERY WORTH the 30 mins to do the tutorial 2 or 3x. Otherwise, I suggest that you subcontract this job and learn from the contractor. The site you are trying to build is very complex and it sounds like you might have a tough time with it. It is better to subcontract and lose the profits than to fail and lose your reputation.

Comment: Thnak you so much for your help, and suggestion. http://barbajs.org/demos.html, its is working now. i did some stuff changes in script. Then it is working. I will use this for my project.

Comment: Glad to hear the good report - congratulations! Please remember to upvote and choose a correct answer if appropriate.